# Where I can find, export or download the biggest list of all .onion addresses?

Tags: onion-services, onion-routing

Where or how I can find, export or download the biggest list of all hidden service .onion addresses?

Comment: Interesting question!!! You have my up vote!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can extract the list from Hidden Service lists and search engines which are available at [OnionDir - Deep Web Link Directory](https://dirnxxdraygbifgc.tor2web.org/).

Or you can try [Ahmia.fi](https://ahmia.fi/) site which is gathering .onion addresses using various methods by crawling the hidden services, downloading visited page data from the Tor2web nodes, and users can use an HTML form to add new addresses. List of the hidden onion sites can be found at [Onion domain list at ahmia.fi](https://ahmia.fi/address/) (over 1000).

Other lists:

- [List of Tor hidden services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Tor_hidden_services)
- [Onion URL List at DarkSpider](http://darkspider.info/index.php/onion-url-list) (over 2400)
- [Huge list of hidden services](http://www.reddit.com/r/onions/comments/1zeve6/huge_list_of_hidden_services/) at Reddit
- [onions-list.txt](https://github.com/kenorb/cicada-2014/blob/master/stage11/scripts/onions-list.txt) at GitHub (over 3200)

---

Other methods:

- Use Google, e.g.:

  ```
  "http?://*.onion" OR "http?://*.onion.tor2web" OR "http?://*.tor2web.org" OR "http?://*.onion.cab/"
  site:websitedown.info/*.onion OR site:websitenotworking.com/*.onion
  ```

Answer (score 5):

Harry71 has a list of onion-hosts which provide a public web site, which you can get in machine readable format.

http://skunksworkedp2cg.onion/sites.txt

It gets updated fairly often.

Answer (score 2):

This one is only for onion-services supporting HTTP, but it is updated daily and are typically up.

http://onion.city/sitemap.xml