# How do I find onion sites?

Tags: onion-services

I heard one of my more software savvy friends at work telling me about the Tor Browser and about the deep web. I'm curious to find out what I can see. But I can't actually figure out how to get there. I'm not huge on knowing how VPN and IP addresses work but I even used DuckDuckGo and couldn't find anything besides normal sites. I haven't been able to find any .onion sites.

Comment: list onion [siteonion.cc](http://siteonion.cc ) interes sites

Comment: This question should be closed on the basis that it has already been asked and answered several times before. The answer from Jobiwan below refers to perhaps the most comprehensive answer which is at http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3896/where-i-can-find-export-or-download-the-biggest-list-of-all-onion-addresses . That, at least, gives a very large list of .onion sites. If the original poster is specifically interested in search engines, then they might need to clarify the question.

Answer (score 10):

There are many onion sites that are basically lists of onion sites. But many of those are not maintained or not well. Here are some links to find more links:

- http://skunksworkedp2cg.onion/sites.html
  Harry71 - An auto-generated up to date list of sites. Search inside that page for 'links' and 'directory'.
- http://msydqstlz2kzerdg.onion/search/
  ahmia.fi - a search engine.
- http://xmh57jrzrnw6insl.onion/
  Torch - a search engine.

DuckDuckGo is available as a hidden service, but as far as I know it does not crawl and index hidden services.

Also see [this related question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3896/where-i-can-find-export-or-download-the-biggest-list-of-all-onion-addresses).