# How to connect tor to a specific ip address of the list?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, ip-address

I have already installed the latest version of Tor but i can't connect to a specific IP address from this Tor list http://torstatus.blutmagie.de/

Can someone help me (also with a practical example...)?

I have windows machine.

Comment: have you installed Tor or Tor Browser Bundle? Which IP are you trying to connect? And what do you mean by 'can't connect'? Are you getting any error? How are you trying to connect? Please add these information to your question

Comment: 1) I think Tor browser bundle from this page https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#downloads   2) I read that should use vidalia but when istall it, make connect error with tor. So i no have idea to make a connession without this.

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to an IP on http://torstatus.blutmagie.de/ ? Tor Browser should automatically route you through the Tor network.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood your ques, you want to exit from one specific Tor exit nodes. So for this, you can do the following.
1. Download Tor Browser Bundle and install it.
2. Go to ..\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor
3. You will find a file torrc. Edit this file with notepad.
4. At the end add "ExitNodes IP" without the quotes. E.g. Exitnodes 46.165.223.217

Answer (score 1):

> but i can't connect to a specific IP address from this Tor list

That is not a list of web servers / web sites. It is a list of relays.
Your client will automatically pick 3 of those to make a circuit.

You can browse the normal web anonymously with your Tor browser. 
If you're looking for .onion sites, [see this question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4619/how-do-i-find-onion-sites).

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to download Vidalia. It has been deprecated. You can just download the `.exe` file from [here](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#downloads) and follow the Windows Instructions down [this page](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#downloads) to install/run tor browser.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into proxychains-ng which allows you to hop through a specific set of proxy ip addresses you set in a config file. Works great in my experience and added benefit of using more hops than Tor as you wish.