# Retrieving addresses of hidden tor services

Tags: configuration, onion-services

Is it practical to generate onion addresses and attempt to connect to them via the tor client or is there a better approach? How can one get an estimate of the number of services available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely impractical to shoot in random directions hoping to hit something. There are roughly 10^24 possible addresses, and roughly 10^4 actual live onions. (If you can do 100/sec, you will have 1 hit per 30 billion years on average.)

More viable methods are to run a crawler, or possibly to run a HSDir and log descriptors.

If you just want to find onions, see this question: [How do I find onion sites?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4619/how-do-i-find-onion-sites)

Comment: The answer states that many of the respective sites are not maintained. How are these sites maintained? Users simply send in their address of their hidden service?

Comment: It differs. There are sites where people can submit onions, there are crawlers, there are wiki's. These are mostly 'just' someones hobby project.  Sometimes hobby projects get abandoned or interrupted by real life.

Comment: If one were to write a crawler would it take the brute force approach or are there more effective methods? Do you know of any such crawlers?

Comment: A web crawler starts by reading a web page. It extracts the links from it and reads those, repeats this process. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler  I don't know of any that you can just download and run.

Comment: I thought of a more in depth approach that computed URLs based on some criteria. And I wanted to ask, the hex string on your profile, what encoding does it have? I've converted it to ASCII and the results is made of mostly unprintable characters, and the length does not appear to fit exactly anything (that I know of) related to tor. Nvm https://torstatus.blutmagie.de/router_detail.php?FP=46b1c969d0a45cae908ecc7ec0fef7ef4c855961

Comment: It is the fingerprint of my relay: https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/46B1C969D0A45CAE908ECC7EC0FEF7EF4C855961