# What are all the suffixes for websites exclusive to Tor, or at least should be opened only on Tor, and how do I find more?

Tags: onion-services

I just started using the Tor Browser and Orbot on my smartphone and would like to find out what I can do with it. Is there a lot of different Legal and Illegal services?

Comment: I know there's .cc and .info.

Comment: probably worth a look: https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/4619/5234

Answer (score 1):

1. `.cc` and `.info` are completely normal [TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain)s!
   to be more precise: [`.cc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.cc) is a [country code top-level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain) (ccTLD) and [`.info`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.info) is a [generic top-level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain) (gTLD).
2. according to [RFC 7686](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7686) `.onion` is reserved and so it can't be registered.
   only `.onion` is reserved in conjunction with Tor, not any other domain!
3. `.onion`-domains are self-governing resp. self-authenticating because there is no central instance to register a domain, and there is also no [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System). - thus the "names" are not so easy to remember.
4. to resolve an `.onion`-domain resp. reach its site and view it, you need a Tor client (as you obviously know).
   there are also gateways ([Tor2web](https://www.tor2web.org/)) to view `.onion`-sites with normal clearnet-browsers, but it is not advised to use them (except you really know what you are doing) because you are still in the clearnet and **not** anonymous!
5. in the deepweb you can use normal clearweb search engines, which also provide a hidden service... but hardly any of them will give you hidden services as results.

- [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/): http://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/
- a bunch of [Searx-instances](https://github.com/asciimoo/searx/wiki/Searx-instances): http://searxes.qzuep6lk6m4n24vzca65voarzvmwvpk2lew3akmxuzndpjw6hdyjx6ad.onion/
- [MetaGer](https://metager.org/): http://b7cxf4dkdsko6ah2.onion/

6. thats the point where you have to use one of the deepweb search engines which searches the deepweb...

- [Ahmia.fi](https://ahmia.fi/): http://msydqstlz2kzerdg.onion/
- TORCH: http://xmh57jrzrnw6insl.onion/

7. *additional:* there are also directory/index-sites in the deepweb and clearnet, which collect useful links to several hidden services:

- [The Hidden Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hidden_Wiki): originally located at http://6sxoyfb3h2nvok2d.onion/
- http://hiddenwikitor.com/
- etc.

Answer (score 1):

See [Tor's address spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/address-spec.txt).

So, yes, at this time, `.onion` is the only TLD that is dedicated to Tor.

Answer (score 0):

domains finishing with ".onion" can be visited with Tor software, for example blabla223344.onion means you can visit this website with Tor software. well, you can visit website of wikileaks or theintercept and they have URL for visiting their websites with Tor software, but you can also use ahmia.fi - a search engine, the same as Torch. for example, I just visited wikileaks and they say wlupld3ptjvsgwqw.onion is their website behind the tor network, when I tried ahmia.fi the first link was the same wlupld3ptjvsgwqw.onion

if you want to find list of darknet markets, you can visit deepdotweb.com website, but I would recommend you always to use tor to visit it or some public PC in the library, don't use your home computer because many websites can be honeypot, they record your IP address and collect information who uses deepweb and bitcoins. I think some websites will not let you to visit it if you use tor, maybe even deepdotweb will refuse you if it is behind cloudflare and similar. they force you to use javascript, etc. and don't forget that many websites are published before 5 years and now they are dead, not working any more. you can find many sites publishing list of onion domains, but when you try to visit these websites, it is not working, because it is dead.