# Where can I find the latest URLs on Tor?

Tags: url

Where can I find the Wiki that includes the latest addresses for websites?

Comment: perhaps useful for you: https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/3896/5234 or [this answer starting with point 5](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/19302/5234).

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need just the wiki? There are few (many) onion link directories: http://vps7nsnlz3n4ckiie5evi5oz2znes7p57gmrvundbmgat22luzd4z2id.onion/ (fresh onions), http://donionsixbjtiohce24abfgsffo2l4tk26qx464zylumgejukfq2vead.onion/ (Onion link list), https://ahmia.fi/address/ aka http://msydqstlz2kzerdg.onion/address/, http://visitorfi5kl7q7i.onion/address/, http://www.cb3rob.org/darknet/ aka http://cb3rob5vwac2dtyc.onion/darknet/ aka http://acjhxk5yqwnw2jdu.onion/ aka http://llk4g25qoey7vf5a.onion/ aka http://darktugaf7rp27uc.onion/ aka http://zljgfn5dna2hsefo.onion/ aka http://darkxnlofu2bby27.onion/, etc.