# Linsk to hidden service sites are broken

Tags: onion-services

I'm new to hidden service sites. There are some hidden wiki online, but most of the onion-links are broken, site doesn't existe anymore.

Is there a hidden wiki or something else with working links? How do you find your sites? Is there a list of stats which sites has the most users?

Tyvm!

Answer (score 0):

That situation is very common with .onion sites. The often illegal nature of many such sites cause them to go offline without notice. Since nobody knows who is operation an .onion site, the operator can in most cases not be contacted.

I'd argue that this is not a question related to Tor. The Tor network online provides the infrastructure to run .onion sites, it does not run them itself.

There is no current and comprehensive list of .onion sites I know of. And it is hardly possible such a list can and will ever exist.

Answer (score 0):

Look at these two questions:
[Where I can find, export or download the biggest list of all .onion addresses?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3896/where-i-can-find-export-or-download-the-biggest-list-of-all-onion-addresses)
[How do I find onion sites?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4619/how-do-i-find-onion-sites)

Onion sites come and go. Link pages get abandoned. As user66 wrote, it is common to find dead links. (In many ways, the .onion web is like the 1990's web.)